# How to create/update Avro schema based on CSV header

Tags: java, apache, csv, avro

I was able to create the AVRO schema using schema builer(using below code). I can say this is static way of generating

Here is my question, how can i create/update Avro schema Json (.avsc file) by reading the CSV file headers/data.

any suggestion please?

Schema ratingSchema = SchemaBuilder.record("Rating").fields().name("id").type().intType().noDefault().
                    name("employeeNAme").type().intType().noDefault().name("rating").type().intType().noDefault().
                    name("Salary").type().intType().noDefault().endRecord();

{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Rating",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "id",
        "type": "int"
    },
    {
        "name": "employeeName",
        "type": "String"
    },
    {
        "name": "rating",
        "type": "int"
    },
    {
        "name": "Salary",
        "type": "int"
    }]
}

Comment: I am wondering about the same thing. Is this accepted when you commit the schema to a registry, e.g. Confluent Schema Registry?